# How to use child <template> tags per directive/component invocation to create dynamic templates?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-directives

I'm trying to port an AngularJS directive over to VueJS, but I have been unable to crack this particular nut...

To put it simply, I have a "generic" list directive. Under each invocation of the directive is a `<template>` tag that defines how the `tbody` is rendered. In AngularJS I was able to accomplish this by DOM-replacing the `tbody[target='true']` in `#myDirectiveBaseTemplate` with the contents of `my-directive > template` per invocation of `<my-directive>` (plus a little `$compile` service majic mixed in to make it a-go-go).

VueJS doesn't seem to give me access to this low-level functionality, or when it (kinda sorta) does it doesn't give me a reference to the current `_element` so I do not have access to each invocation's `<template>` tag.

The simplified AngularJS directive code is defined something like this:

```
<my-directive data="some.list" mapping="[ 'property', 'property2' ]">
    <template>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in data">
                <td>{{item.property}}</td>
                <td>{{item.property2}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </template>
</my-directive>
```

`myDirective` first pulls in the base `text/ng-template`, which looks something like this:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myDirectiveBaseTemplate">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr ng-repeat="prop in mapping" ng-click="doSort(prop)">
                {{prop}}
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody target="true"></tbody>
    </table>
</script>
```

During render, `tbody[target='true']` in `#myDirectiveBaseTemplate` is DOM-replaced with each invocation's `my-directive > template` whereby creating custom HTML for each invocation of `my-directeive` based on each embedded `template`.

So... how in the hell do I accomplish this in VueJs?!?

**EDIT 1:**

A Second invocation of `my-directive` could looks like this:

```
<my-directive data="some.list" mapping="[ 'order.delivered', 'person.name', 'person.dob' ]">
    <template>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in data">
                <td>{{item.order.delivered ? 'Delivered' : ''}}</td>
                <td>{{item.person.name}}</td>
                <td>{{item.person.dob | format:'yyyy-mm-dd'}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </template>
</my-directive>
```

And just to note, the example above has been simplified. `my-directive` actually can define up to 5 different `<template>`s within itself to modify various parts of the "generic" list (e.g. `<template type='row'>`, `<template type='help'>`, etc.). However, all serve the same purpose; to modify/add-to various parts of the DOM of the underlying directive's HTML.

Comment: Can you please add an example of how the `my-directive > tbody template` will be customized / different for each invocation of `my-directive`, except of showing different items ?

Comment: Seems like you're looking for scoped slots

Comment: @StephenThomas Maybe, but the issue I've had is getting access to the `<template>`s to manip. the DOM. I tend to be able to access one or the other (the main `template` OR the `_element`s `<template>` tags but not both) at a given point in the render :( OR VueJS has removed the `<template>` tags (at `binding`) even early in the lifecycle.

Comment: 'DOM manipulation' is not clear enough statement, because Vue.js has many tools to bind the DOM to the components state. Vue allows you to access the DOM itself with: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements
But the best-practice is to first look for more framework-ish way to achieve the desired result

Answer (score 1):

I weren't able to understand if there is a case when your `<template>`
is going to create "custom HTML for each invocation of `my-directive`" except of showing different item properties at each table row.
If this only the difference between invocations so your Vue.js components templates could simply look like:

Vue.js `ChildTbodyComponent.vue` Template:

```
<tbody>
    <tr v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
        <td>{{item.property}}</td>
        <td>{{item.property2}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Vue.js `ParentTableComponent.vue` Template:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr v-for="header in headers" :key="header.name" @click="doSort(header)">
            {{header.name}}
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <child-tbody-component :items="arrayOfDataForRows"></child-tbody-component>
</table>
```

Comment: The example above has been simplified quite a bit. I actually have 5 different `<template>`'s that define various parts of the table/directive; Title Bar controls Left and Right, TBODY, Tooltip and Help (but they all serve the same general purpose, small-ish parts that are integrated into the larger list control).